# How to let compiler do loop invariant code motion with std::map?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, stdmap

Here is a part of my code: (note that `M` is a large number)

```
void myFunc(std::map<int, int>& myMap, int** arr) {

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) { 
            arr[i][j] = myMap[i] * j + i;
        } 
    }

}
```

`myMap[i]` is a loop invariant in the inner loop. So I think gcc will automatically move it out of the inner loop when I use `-O1`. But it does not work. Since when I manually move like the following:

```
void myFunc(std::map<int, int>& myMap, int** arr) {

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { 
        int tmp = myMap[i]; 
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) { 
            arr[i][j] = tmp * j + i;
        } 
    }

}
```

The runtime is much better than the first version.

Maybe compiler thinks `myMap` would modify the map so it chooses not to do the optimization. But I am sure that I just want to read the value of `myMap` and will not modify it. How can I make compiler understand?

Comment: If key does not exist in the `myMap` it will be created in `myMap[i]` call. So how the compiler should know if `myMap` contents is unchanged after first and each next iteration?

Comment: This can only work if `myMap` is a `const&` and even then I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that the map `operator[]` always returns a modifiable reference to the value, so the compiler can't assume it's safe to move it outside that inner loop. That's because the operator will insert the value if it's not there. Which is probably *not* what you want.

It's easy enough to fix by instead iterating over the map using only `const` methods. You can pass the map to `myFunc` as a `const&`, and then use the `cbegin()` and `cend()` member functions to get references to the values stored in it.

E.g.:

```
void myFunc(const std::map<int, int>& m, int** arr) {
    int i = 0;
    auto it = m.cbegin();
    while (it != m.cend()) { // assumes m.size() == N
        for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = (*it).second * j + i;
        }
        it++;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Here's a few quick benchmarks on my machine, for `N=10` and `M=1000000`. (I ran each a few times, these are somewhere in the middle.)

Your original version:

```
real   0m0.449s
user   0m0.434s
sys    0m0.012s
```

Your second version:

```
real   0m0.162s
user   0m0.148s
sys    0m0.012s
```

My solution:

```
real   0m0.176s
user   0m0.162s
sys    0m0.012s
```

Your second solution actually seems consistently about 10% faster, so if you care about every last bit of speed, just hoist that assignment out yourself.

Comment: You can even use for range: `for (const auto& p: m) { for (int j = 0; j < M; j++) { arr[p.first][j] = p.second * j + p.first; }}`.

Comment: @Jarod42 Sure, that works, but it requires that `p.first` *is* the index into the array. May or may not be true.

Comment: You have mostly a similar assumption (`// assumes m.size() == N`), and my "for range" remark is still valid even if we introduce `i` (as you do).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I think the best way is do the motion by myself. Since there still has some lost in performance.